# Laravel 9: how to open a modal window from a Vue component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a Laravel 9 application. On the Notes page, it displays basic information about notes through a Vue component (called 'note-component'). The vue component fetches the data about notes using an ajax() call and then displays data using v-for directive in a card. In other words, if there are 10 notes, the 'note-component' displays 10 cards containing basic information about notes.

Inside each note card, I want to have a 'More Info' button and on clicking that button, I want to display a modal window to display additional details about that note, and additional functionality to do other stuff on the note, including editing of the note. I would prefer that the note details modal window is vue component, so that any changes are automatically reflected in the parent ('note-component') when the modal window is closed.

Any advise is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see your experience.
What I suggest is to use another `data` value for Note modal dialog.
Let's say we are using `notes` in the list, then we can add `noteEdit` value for the modal.
After we do additional functions on the modal, I would send ajax POST and get response of updated note which eventually update `notes` data in `note-component`